# Discord.js - How do you get a channel's ID?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a `wipe` command and my original idea was to clear messages from that channel but when I found out that the limit for deleting messages is 100, I tried to switch to cloning the channel and then deleting it, but I can't seem to get the channel ID. (I know how to do this manually.)

This is what I've tried:

```
const fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel_id);
```

and then

```
channel.clone(fetchedChannel);
fetchedChannel.delete();
```

Any ideas how to get the channel ID?

Comment: The channel ID of the newly made channel?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how [clone()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=clone) method works.

To clone the channel that you fetched, you need to do: `fetchedChannel.clone()`
then you can delete it with `fetchedChannel.delete()`.

If you want to get the cloned channel you can do:
`const clonedChannel = await fetchedChannel.clone()`